# A fair coin is tossed 13 times and the face that appears is recorded.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this question and I am asked to compute the following probabilities:

- How many elements of the sample space will start or end (or both) with a tail and have a total of exactly two tails
- How many elements of the sample space will start and end with a tail with a total of exactly three tail

Now it has been a while since I have worked with probability other than formulas and simulations. Is there anyway this can be set up as a binomial equation? Or what is the best way to go about beginning this problem?

Comment: you could do a graph, use combinatorics ? etc.

Comment: In both cases, you just have to describe the possible patterns.  For the first, you have three types:  either $TH^{11}T,$ or $TWH$, or $HWT$ where $W$ i a word of length $11$ in $H,T$ which contains exactly $1$ $T$.  Can you count the possible $W$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do the first one is to count the number of length-$13$ $HT$ strings that have exactly two $T$'s, and then subtract the number of length-$11$ strings with exactly two $T$'s, because those represent the strings where neither the first, nor the last, element are tails.

$$\binom{13}{2}-\binom{11}{2} = 78 - 55 = 23$$

The second is easier. Since the sequence starts *and* ends with a tail, you just need to count the number of places the third tail can occur. That's $\binom{11}{1}$

When you asked, in your question, "Is there anyway this can be set up as a binomial equation?", I'm not sure exactly what you meant by "binomial equation". These counting tools we're using are "binomial coefficients", which are used to count combinations.

Comment: Thank you. This made sense. I was referring to using a binomial distribution to solve the problem.

Comment: The binomial distribution would only come up if there is a question of probabilities in a binomial experiment. Since this is just a counting question, no distribution is necessary. Of course, binomial distribution formulas also use binomial coefficients.

Comment: Yes. I realized after I posted this that I was entering probabilities and it was looking for counts. Still helpful though. Thank you!